# Reading one column of data and creating a log graph from a csv

Tags: python, csv, logging

I have data from a spectrometer from Ocean Optics and am trying to extract the right hand column of data to create a log intensity time graph. I'm currently having issues extracting the intensity data from the csv. This is what the data looks like:

[image: 1]

The data intensity data starts on the 18th line of code and ends on line 3665. I only need the second column of data.
So far I have this,

```
import csv

with open('TEST000.csv') as csv_file:
    data = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in list(data)[18:3665]:
        print(row)
```

But when I run the code it doesn't work and doesn't extract the data correctly.

How do I get this to work? Also any help of converting the data into a log graph would also be appreciated

Comment: Can you please instead of an image have it's text?  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use `csv.reader` on a file that is not a csv. instead try something like this:

```
with open('TEST000.csv') as csv_file:
    for row in list(csv_file)[18:3665]:
        print(row)
```

This will give you each row and you can split the values of each entry in the list by using the `split()` method. Something like:

```
with open('TEST000.csv') as csv_file:
    for row in list(csv_file)[18:3665]:
        print(row.split(" ")[1])
```

EDIT: don't forget to close your file after you're done with `csv_file.close()`